# What is the best way present graphically the significance of a large number of 32 T-tests?

Tags: statistics

I have 4 factors to adjust to either a high set, or a low set. I set factor 1 (F1) high, collected my sample; i then set F1 low, and collect another sample; F2 - F4 is constant throughout; I have data now to do T-test to see if changing F1 results in significant sample difference.

I continue collecting samples for all factors adjusted at either High and Low level (while keeping other factors unchanged), for a total of 16 samples. I then can do a grand total of 32 T-tests!

The problem! How do i present T-test results (significant diff or not) graphically? Is it even possible?

How then should i present this data? Really a appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a [4-cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract), label the vertices by the corresponding factor settings (so that each of the four displacement directions corresponds to a factor axis), and thicken/color each edge by the $t$-statistics (since these *should* be intercomparable with this experiment design -- although I'd check that be ensuring that sorting the $t$s also sorts to the $p$-values).

I'd probably pick the diagram with two cubes displaced diagonally, with the corresponding vertices between the two cubes joined by edges.  It's the fourth diagram [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tesseract#/media/File:Dimension_levels.svg).  Notice that the edge colors correspond to a factor change.